# My Java Internet connectivity check always fails

Tags: java

I need to check for Internet connectivity in my Java app. I created this simple program, but it always says false.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Internet {

public static void main(String args[]){
    String host = "209.85.175.104";
    int timeOut = 10000; // I recommend 3 seconds at least
    try {
        boolean status = InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeOut);
        System.out.println(status);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

}
```

I tried `String host = "www.google.com";` I got that IP address by pinging in my terminal and copying it.

Answer (score 3):

According to the javadoc http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29 it will try ICMP Echo requests, and if it can't do that it will try reaching the host on port 7 (echo). Most likely firewall problems for the first, and I doubt that google has port 7 open.

Can you just attempt to connect and if that fails, then say the host is not reachable? i.e. is there a specific reason you need to check first?